# SQL - Combine 2 rows, unflatten data and convert columns into individual rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am currently working with an audit log table similar to:

```
ID  |  EventKey            |  AccessID  |  AccessType  |  Status  |  Final
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | ABC123               |  NULL      |  123         |  335     |   OK
2   | ABC123               |  985521    |  NULL        |  66      |   OK
....
41  | ABC456               |  NULL      |  456         |  335     |   OK
42  | ABC456               |  113228    |  NULL        |  66      |   OK
```

What I need to do is unflatten this data and essentially return 4 rows based on the values of the two like rows

i.e. -

```
Field      |  FieldValuePrevious  |  FieldValueChanged  | EventKey    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AccessID   | NULL                 | 985521              | ABC123       
AccessType | 123                  | NULL                | ABC123             
Status     | 335                  | 66                  | ABC123               
Final      | OK                   | OK                  | ABC123
```

If it's difficult to do via inline SQL, I can convert to a stored procedure as well.

Comment: You seem to be storing numbers and character strings in the same column.  That seems like a bad idea.

Comment: The data is actually made up.  In practice we're not storing both data types in the same column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have to do each field individually.  Let me show how to do this using SQL Server 2012:

```
select 'AccessId' as field, prev_accessid as ValuePrevious,
       accessid as ValueChanged, eventkey
from (select id, eventkey, accessid,
             lag(id) over (partition by eventkey order by id) as prev_id
             lag(accessid) over (partition by eventkey order by id) as prev_accessid
      from auditlog al
     ) al
where prev_id is not null and
      not (prev_accessid = accessid or prev_accessid is null and accessid is null);
```

EDIT:

You can replace the `lag()` function with a correlated subquery:

```
select 'AccessId' as field, prev_accessid as ValuePrevious,
       accessid as ValueChanged, eventkey
from (select id, eventkey, accessid,
             lag1.id as prev_id
             lag1.accessid as prev_accessid
      from (select al.*,
                   (select top 1 id
                    from auditlog al2
                    where al2.eventkey = al.eventkey and
                          al2.id < al.id
                    order by al2.id desc
                   ) as lag1id
            from auditlog al
           ) al left outer join
           auditlog lag1
           on al.lag1id = lag1.id
     ) al
where prev_id is not null and
      not (prev_accessid = accessid or prev_accessid is null and accessid is null);
```

Comment: unforutnately I am on SQL 2008.. can't use the lag() function. Any other ideas?